# What is the UI solution of IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDE's UI is much faster than Eclipse. And as we know that it is written in Java, I wonder what the UI is written in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI of IntelliJ is written in 100% Java and I'm fairly certain that it uses [JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). As opposed to eclipse, which uses [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) (that is, native code).

Comment: isn't it said that SWT is much faster than Swing? How did they managed to do that?

Comment: @Adam You almost certainly have that backward. JDBC drivers without native code (e.g. Type-4 drivers) are much faster then drivers with native code. There is a stiff performance penalty paid to establish a call into native code (in part due to context switching) from Java.

Comment: UI normally takes a very small part of the CPU time, be it Swing or SWT. Most slowness you notice is caused by non-UI issues, e.g. the algorithms used by the IDE for code analysis, or just plain garbage collection.